# iPhone: is it possible to route calls to speaker only if answering via smartwatch?

Tags: iphone, audio, speakers

Usually I answer calls with the standard iPhone receiver. Sometimes, while the phone is charging and I'm in the other room, I have to answer the call with a bluetooth-connected smartwatch (otherwise I wouldn't make it in time,) then I have to run to the other room and press the speaker button to start the conversation.

Note: on the smartwatch I just press "answer call" but it has no speaker, so the call is completely handled by the phone itself.

I know it is possible to route audio to the speaker by default, but is there a way to do that only if I'm triggering the "answer call" from the smartwatch?

Comment: You may wish to edit your question to specify the smartwatch. I assume it is not an Apple watch, which does indeed have a speaker and functions itself as a speaker phone when you answer a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's unfortunately not currently possible.

As you indicate, you can use the Call Audio Routing functionality in Accessibility to always route any call to speaker. However, you cannot do that just for calls answered through a Bluetooth-enabled smart watch.

Comment: I feared that, I also tried to fiddle with commands to set audio default routing to speakers when charging but no luck with that either...